# Identifier for a dynamic ImageView

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android-imageview

I'm building an app where I have to change the source of an ImageView element in my layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="24sp"/>

<ImageView 
    android:id="@android:id/image1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/res0"
    android:contentDescription="@string/description" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@android:id/text2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the same layout I have a TextView element, where I have defined `android:id="@android:id/text1"` as identifier. On my activity I then change the text accordingly to the user input (in this particular case the current tab the user is on), like this:

```
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_scientist, container, false);
   Bundle args = getArguments();
   int id = args.getInt(ARG_SCIENTIST_ID);
   TextView name = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
   TextView description = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
   ImageView image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.image1);
   if (id == 1) {
      name.setText(getString(R.string.name1));
      description.setText(getString(R.string.text1));
      image.setImageResource(R.drawable.res1);
   } else {
      name.setText(getString(R.string.name2));
      description.setText(getString(R.string.text2));
      image.setImageResource(R.drawable.res2);
   }
```

I tried the same thing on the ImageView, setting `android:id="@android:id/image1"`, but Eclipse keeps saying that no resource has been found that matches the given name. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By using `android.R.id.text1` you are not creating an id but are using an in-built id, however there is no in-built `android.R.id.image1`.

You need to create your own ID for the ImageView, so in your XML instead of

```
android:id="@android:id/image1"
```

do

```
android:id="@+id/image1"
```

this tells the compiler to create a new id called `image1` at compile time. Ids created this way are not accessible through `android.R.id.???` as this is used for in-built ids only, so in your Activity instead of

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.image1);
```

do

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
```

Comment: Works! What are those reserved id's used for actually?

Comment: @Ciambello They are there mainly because you are required to use the built in ids to use the functionality of certain elements, for example to use `ListActivity` your layout must have a `ListView` with `id="@android:id/list"`